# Autocomplete MessageSource in JSF in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Tags: java, jsf, localization, internationalization, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA (ultimate ed., v12.1.3) on my project. We use JSF to display our pages and `messages_en.properties` (or *_different_language) to handle i18n/l10n.

.properties files are handled by our custom implementation of `org.springframework.context.MessageSource` interface.

Within a JSF page, I'd like Idea to autocomplete/link to our .properties files, eg. with code like this:

```
<!--@elvariable id="msg" type="org.springframework.context.MessageSource"-->
<ib:output_text value="#{msg.base_client_name}"/>
```

the `{msg.base_client_name}` should be "clickable" (and not marked as warning "cannot resolve property or method base_client_name). Is there a way how to configure idea to do this? I know this worked on a different project, but I don't have access to the project configuration anymore.

Comment: With standard properties files, this works already out the box in standard Eclipse trim. If that also works for you in IntelliJ, then you should reframe your question in such way to ask about it in Spring context (as it's likely the cause of breaking properties file autocomplete support). You've namely tagged it nowhere, so you won't reach the right audience.

Comment: I am facing the same problem within our project. Have you figured out, how to link a l10n file to jsf yet? I would appreciate any help very much, thank you.